# Does Kqueue need close like epoll?

Tags: sockets, c++11

Does Kqueue handler need close ? I mean :

```
int hd = epoll_create(512);
  ....
  close(hd); // we have to close
```

so for kqueue, does it need Close ?

```
int hd = kqueue();
  ...
  close(hd) ? // is this a must ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Kqueue uses a file descriptor, exactly like epoll, meaning that it should be closed when you're done with it.

Mostly, the OS cleanup will close it if you didn't do so before the process terminated... however, this is considered a bad practice.

Comment: @NeoLiu , you're welcome :-) If you're happy with the answer, please accept the answer and/or up vote it (you can always do this in your own questions)... as a side note, I suggest you consider avoiding "thank you" comments in order to keep the comment space informative (that's what many of us do and it used to be mentioned in one of the community guides).